# Storing formulas in a table to be calculated later?

Tags: postgresql, pandas

What is the best way to store metric formulas in a database? In the beginning, I just threw the raw columns to a visualization tool and it calculated metrics for me. I quickly learned that there are many (valid) exceptions to the standard rules due to client requirements, etc. I am now considering whether I should create numerator and denominator columns during the ETL/database layer, or right as I send the data to the visualization tool.

I was considering using Python evaluate to read a string which would be stored in a Postgres table:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html

Pardon the formatting, but I have three columns below. One column to tie back to a specific project, and then two example metrics.

```
id                          productive_time                        productive_status
165 "productive_time = talk_time + hold_time + after_call_work_time"    "productive_status = status_3_time + status_4_time + status_5_time"
1911    "productive_time = talk_time + hold_time + after_call_work_time + ring_time"    "productive_status = status_7_time + status_8_time"
```

Then, in the visualization layer, the metric calculation would simply be `SUM(productive_time) / SUM(call_count)` compared to having potentially dozens of calculations.

Does this make sense, are there other best practices?

The alternative is to have massive CASE WHEN statements, I suppose. But there are literally several hundred - over a thousand ids to cover. 95% of them will be the same though.

Edit:

[image]

```
for x in range(0, len(df['inbound_time_formula'].unique())):
    df.loc[df['inbound_time_formula'] == df['inbound_time_formula'].unique()[x], 'inbound_time'] = df.eval(df['inbound_time_formula'].unique()[x], inplace=True)
```

I tried to df.eval the dataframe, but it appears to apply to the entire dataframe rather than just the rows where the formula is present.

Answer (score 0):

rules:

```
t=# create table rl(id serial,tm text, sm text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into rl(tm,sm) values('a+b-c','a*b +c');
INSERT 0 1
```

data:

```
t=# create table dt(i serial,a int,b int, c int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into dt(a,b,c) select 1,2,3;
INSERT 0 1
```

example:

```
t=# create or replace function rlf(rid int,did int) returns table (rsm int,rtm int) as $$
begin
return query execute format('select '||(select sm from rl where id=rid)||', '||(select tm from rl where id=rid)||' from dt where i=%s',did);
end;
$$ language plpgsql
;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# select * from rlf(1,1);
 rsm | rtm
-----+-----
   5 |   0
(1 row)
```

the approach is very much questionable as you cant avoid injection by definition - you don't parse rule - executing it as is...

Comment: To alleviate some risk, I would certainly be doing the evaluation in memory and not within the DB (I would use python to do so). Are there any general best practices when dealing with N ways to measure a single value?

Comment: well, you can add check constraint on rule columns to allow only numbers, special characters andcolu names